# Get the value of a record type from another package in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
packageA Body
MEMBER FUNCTION getValue (indx IN PLS_INTEGER) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
colData packageB.vldtnR
BEGIN
colData := packageB.getColumnData(indx);
--I want to output the id and name from the specified index
END;

packageB Header
TYPE vldtnR IS RECORD(
id PLS_INTEGER;
name VARCHAR2(50)
)

packageB Body
TYPE vldtnArryT IS TABLE OF vldtnR INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
vldtnArry vldnArryT;

FUNCTION getColumnData(indx IN PLS_INTEGER) IS
BEGIN
 IF vldtnArry.EXISTS(indx) = TRUE THEN
    RETURN vldtnArry(indx);
 END IF;
END;
```

Code Overview:

vldtnArry pertains to vldArryT (PackageB body)

vldtnArryT pertains to vldtnR (PackageB body)

vldtnR is in PackageB header

Question:

How do I output the id and name of an index in packageA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Maksim said, you have a `colData` variable which is a record type, so you can refer to the fields as `colData.id` and `colData.name`. You want to return both as a single string based on the `varchar2` return type and the embedded comment, so you can do:

```
CREATE PACKAGE BODY packageA AS
  FUNCTION getValue (indx IN PLS_INTEGER) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
  colData packageB.vldtnR;
  BEGIN
    colData := packageB.getColumnData(indx);
    return 'Index ' || indx || ' ID ' || colData.id
      || ' name "' || colData.name || '"';
  END;
END;
/
```

Which will return something like this, which you can obviously modify to your desired output:

```
Index 2 ID 13 name "Thirteen"
```

The code you posted has numerous other problems, hopefully from retyping it here. [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71e02/1) which compiles and lets you see the result for a couple of index values, bases on a manually-populated collection.

Answer (score 2):

In `colData` you have a record, you can call the fields from the record directly as `colData.id` and `colData.name`.